# SQL Server 2016 named constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does a named constraint get deleted when the table & database they belong to is deleted? In my case I get an error that the named constraint already exists when I re-run the create table code.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyBakery;
USE MyBakery;

CREATE TABLE BCus_OrderType 
(
    Cus_OrderTypeID INT,
    Cus_Type VARCHAR(20) 
        CONSTRAINT Bkry_OrderType_NN_Type NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Bkry_OrderType_Unq_Type UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(Cus_OrderTypeID)
);
```

If now I delete the database

```
DROP DATABASE Mybakery;
```

and re-run the code

```
CREATE DATABASE MyBakery;
USE MyBakery;

CREATE TABLE BCus_OrderType 
(
    Cus_OrderTypeID INT,
    Cus_Type VARCHAR(20) 
        CONSTRAINT Bkry_OrderType_NN_Type NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Bkry_OrderType_Unq_Type UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(Cus_OrderTypeID)
);
```

I get an error that the constraint name already exists.

How can I delete this named constraint?

Please note that I have already deleted the database but somehow the named constraint still exists.

Comment: Note that I ran the same table creation script on a clean database, and I did not get an error.

Comment: @Paul You are right, thanks for the effort. it seems that i assigned the same named constraint to two different fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Transact-SQL**

USE master ;
GO
DROP DATABASE Mybakery, ....... ;
GO

Comment: Does not work. Cannot drop the database 'Mybakery', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: appreciate the effort. mistake is on my end.

Answer (score 0):

**can you try this**:

USE MyBakery;
GO
DROP DATABASE Mybakery;
GO

**or**
**Using SQL Server Management Studio**

1- In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.

2- Expand Databases, right-click the database to delete, and then click Delete.

3- Confirm the correct database is selected, and then click OK.